# Comparison of Gravitation pull on moon due to sun and earth

Tags: newtonian-gravity

Gravitational pull on moon due to sun is almost twice than that of earth on moon. 
Then why doesn't moon escape towards sun like on solar eclipse?

Comment: Hint: ask yourself the same question about the Earth